# How to send emails in bulk using python?

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I've made a django website that I would like to get out in the world. I want to get in touch with various youtubers to promote my site so I wrote the following code which was SUPPOSED TO send emails to all of them.

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import smtplib
import time

email_sender = 'myemail@gmail.com'
with open('google_password.txt') as f:
    email_password = f.read()
subject = 'Subject of the email'
body = """
Contents of my email

"""
def send_email(email_receiver):
   
    em = EmailMessage()
    em['From'] = email_sender
    em['To'] = email_receiver
    em['Subject'] = subject
    em.set_content(body)

    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
        smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
        smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, em.as_string())

email_receivers = [
'53 separate strings containing the emails of 53 youtubers'
]

for email_receiver in email_receivers:
    try:    
        send_email(email_receiver)
        print("Email sent for:", email_receiver)
    except Exception:
        continue
    finally:
        time.sleep(300)

print("Sent all emails.")
```

A few of those emails were mine because I wanted to check if the emails were being sent in my spam folder which was the case. The emails were being sent in the spam folder. I want to know how to go about sending mass emails using python properly (and for free, because I'm broke) without them being sent in the spam folder. A few people suggested services such Amazon SES, Mailgun etc. but I attempted to understand how they worked but I couldn't so please help me out in that regard by describing how I'm supposed to go about solving this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS SES with AWS Lambda

```
import boto3

def send_email(subject, body, recipient, sender):
    ses = boto3.client('ses', region_name='your_region')  # Replace 'your_region' with your AWS region (e.g., 'us-east-1')

    response = ses.send_email(
    Source=sender,
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': [
            recipient,
        ],
    },
    Message={
        'Subject': {
            'Data': subject,
        },
        'Body': {
            'Text': {
                'Data': body,
            },
        },
    }
)

return response

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    subject = "Test Email from Lambda"
    body = "This is a test email sent from AWS Lambda using SES."
    recipient = "recipient@example.com"  # Replace with the recipient's email address
    sender = "sender@example.com"  # Replace with the verified sender's email address

    response = send_email(subject, body, recipient, sender)

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': 'Email sent successfully!',
    'ses_response': response
}
```

You can refer to [Setup SES](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/set-up-aws-simple-email-service/)

NOTE: It is important to ensure that the Lambda execution role has been configured with the necessary permissions to use the SES for sending emails.